# Dividing selected columns by vector in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This has to be simple in base R, but it is driving me crazy with dplyr (which overall has made my life much better!).
Suppose you have the following tibbles

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union



df1 <- tibble(x=seq(5)*19, a1=seq(5)*1, a2=seq(5)*2, a3=seq(5)*4)

df1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>       x    a1    a2    a3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    19     1     2     4
#> 2    38     2     4     8
#> 3    57     3     6    12
#> 4    76     4     8    16
#> 5    95     5    10    20


df2 <- tibble(b1=3, b2=0.5, b3=10)

df2
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      b1    b2    b3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3   0.5    10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Then I simply want to replace in df1 a1 with a1/b1, a2 with a2/b2 and so on.
This has to be general enough to handle the case when I have many columns.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just wanting to `dplyr::transmute()`?

Comment: I am looking for a solution based on mutate(across(a1:a3)), but I cannot write the function to apply.

Comment: @larry77 I don't think this is the right application for `mutate(across(a1:a3))`

Comment: I suppose you are right. In a much more complex case I have at hand, I finally resort to pivot_longer and left_join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowwise()` with `c_across()`

```
df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(c_across(a1:a3) / df2, .keep = "unused") %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#       x    b1    b2    b3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    19 0.333     4   0.4
# 2    38 0.667     8   0.8
# 3    57 1        12   1.2
# 4    76 1.33     16   1.6
# 5    95 1.67     20   2
```

Another base R option

```
df1[-1] <- t(t(df1[-1]) / unlist(df2))
df1

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#       x    a1    a2    a3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    19 0.333     4   0.4
# 2    38 0.667     8   0.8
# 3    57 1        12   1.2
# 4    76 1.33     16   1.6
# 5    95 1.67     20   2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Map`

```
df1[-1] <- Map(`/`, df1[-1], df2)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      x    a1    a2    a3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    19 0.333     4   0.4
#2    38 0.667     8   0.8
#3    57 1        12   1.2
#4    76 1.33     16   1.6
#5    95 1.67     20   2
```

Or if you want a `tidyverse` solution you can use `map2` in `purrr` :

```
df1[-1] <- purrr::map2(df1[-1], df2, `/`)
```

Comment: The closest to what I had in mind. Do you know how to implement this with mutate(across)? Across is the latest goody in dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be:

```
bind_cols(select(df1, x),
          sweep(select(df1, -x), 2, FUN = `/`, unlist(df2)))

      x    a1    a2    a3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    19 0.333     4   0.4
2    38 0.667     8   0.8
3    57 1        12   1.2
4    76 1.33     16   1.6
5    95 1.67     20   2
```

Comment: OK, I had gone this far. I was hoping for something with mutate(across).

Answer (score 0):

Or like this if you have more columns:

```
df1[,2:4] <- df1[,2:4] / df2 %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(df1)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
      x    a1    a2    a3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    19 0.111     8  0.04
2    38 0.222    16  0.08
3    57 0.333    24  0.12
4    76 0.444    32  0.16
5    95 0.556    40  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which considers the column names of your variables and pairs them with the number they have to be divided for. The function `cur_column()` comes in handy inside the `mutate(across())` - the function you wanted to use

```
# vector of divisors
l <- as.list(as.numeric(df2[1,]))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("a"),
                ~ ./l[[na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(cur_column(), "[^[:digit:]]"))))]]))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#       x    a1    a2    a3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    19 0.333     4   0.4
# 2    38 0.667     8   0.8
# 3    57 1        12   1.2
# 4    76 1.33     16   1.6
# 5    95 1.67     20   2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
df1[-1] <- df1[-1]/unlist(df2)[col(df1)]
```